# How can I stop an exception from causing my code to exit?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str1 + str2);
```

Sometimes it gives an exception and in this case I would simply like to return null.

Is there a way I can stop the exception causing the code to exit and instead simply make it return null?

Comment: Yes...execute the code that might throw an exception in a try block, catch the specific exception type (whatever that is) in a catch block, and return null from the catch block. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: Look into `try` / `catch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str1 + str2);
}
catch (JsonReaderException)
{
return null;
}
```

Comment: Except don't catch `Exception`, catch the *specific type of exception* thrown by the `DeserializeObject` method that you want to handle.

Comment: He states he wants to return null when an exception happens. In this case it doesn't matter which exception

Comment: It *always* matters which exceptions. Lots of exceptions were not meant to be caught. Writing `catch (Exception)` is never not a mistake.

Comment: I agree it is best practice. I have added the appropiate Exception :)